# Removing part of package name Android

Tags: java, android

So I am dealing with a conflict. I am trying to launch the google play store from within my app, I have that functionality implemented. But, I can only hardcode the package value in the URI for it to work. I need a way where I can use getPackageName() and it returns the correct one from google play store.

The Google Play Store package name that worked in the URI: `org.horaapps.leafpic`

The Package Name getPackageName() returns: `org.horaapps.leafpic.debug`

Here is the code for launching google play:

```
//Launches to the app in google play, if the package name ever does change you can do this
//by changing the org section of the URI below. -beastlyCoder
Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=org.horaapps.leafpic"); //dont want hardcoded value
Log.d("tag", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());


Intent myAppLinkToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
try
{
    startActivity(myAppLinkToMarket);

} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, " unable to find market app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

How I can I remove the debug at the end so the two packages can correspond, (NOTE: this is an open source project so I'd prefer not making any drastic changes to the code like changing package structure and all of that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your build variant to **release** and add this in your app level *build.gradle*:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        applicationId "org.horaapps.leafpic"
    }

    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ""
    }
}
```